# GCloud N2 machines: 128 vCPUs in 1 chip?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, intel, hardware

I saw that GCloud offers N2 instances with up to 128 vCPUs. I wonder what kind of hardware that is. Do they really put 128 cores into 1 chip? If so, Intel doesn't make them generally available for sale to the public, right? If they use several chips, how do they split the cores? Also, I assume that all cores are on the same node, do they place more than 2 CPU chips on that node or do they have chips with 56 cores (which also is a lot)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily build or purchase a system with 128 vCPUs. Duplicating Google's custom hardware and firmware is another matter. 128 vCPUs is not large today.

Google Cloud publishes the processor families: [CPU platforms](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms)

The Intel Ice Lake Xeon motherboards support multiple processor chips.

With a two-processor motherboard using the 40 core model ([8380](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/212287/intel-xeon-platinum-8380-processor-60m-cache-2-30-ghz.html)), 160 vCPUs are supported.

For your example, Google is using 32-core CPUs.

Note: one physical core is two vCPUs.  [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms)

I am not sure what Google is using for **n2d-standard-224** which supports 224 vCPUs. That might be the Ice Lake 4 processor 28-core models.

> GCloud N2 machines: 128 vCPUs in 1 chip?

Currently, the only processors that support 64 cores (128 vCPUs) that I am aware of are ARM processors from Ampere. That means Google is using one or more processor chips on a multi-cpu motherboard.

> If so, Intel doesn't make them generally available for sale to the
> public, right?

You can buy just about any processor on Amazon, for example.

> If they use several chips, how do they split the cores? Also, I
> assume that all cores are on the same node, do they place more than 2
> CPU chips on that node or do they have chips with 56 cores (which also is a lot)?

You are thinking in terms of laptop and desktop technology. Enterprise rack mounted servers typically support two or more processor chips. This has been the norm for a long time (decades).

Comment: Ampere makes CPUs with 128 *physical* cores. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/ampere-altra-max-128-core-priced  I don't think they use [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) to make a physical core appear as multiple logical cores the way Intel and AMD do for their big-core chips; they're already designed as "efficiency" cores optimized for throughput per area without SMT, because that's a niche ARM cores can be good at.  Not sure if those big ARM chips support multi-socket, though; not needing an interconnect would simplify the design, but mean only 128 cores/server

Comment: The norm for high-density compute servers is still dual-socket, right?  Quad-socket costs significantly more per socket, and doesn't as easily fit in a 1U.  (Or blade?  Do servers still do blades to pack more CPUs into the same rack height by turning the mobos sideways?  That was a thing when I was a sysadmin back in 2003 to 2006 for some small compute clusters.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Lake_(microprocessor)#Ice_Lake-SP_(Xeon_Scalable) has a good table of available CPU models.  And yeah, Platinum ICX goes up to 40 physical cores per socket.  Up from 28 in [Cascade Lake-SP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_Lake_(microarchitecture)#Xeon_Platinum_series), or apparently [Cascade Lake-AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_Lake_(microarchitecture)#Cascade_Lake-AP_(Advanced_Performance)) comes in a 56-core version only available soldered to the motherboard.  I'm guessing that's two dies in one package with too many pins for a normal socket.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Today's servers in the cloud need large amounts of memory. Due to heat generation that often eliminates blade and 1U servers when you factor maxing out memory and high core CPUs. The tradeoff becomes rack space versus cooling costs. However, Google, AWS, etc do not deploy the types of servers you and I know (Proliants for example) as they custom build almost everything just for their datacenters.